# Imageslider won't get in the background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm working on a website and I want to have a Javascript image-slideshow as background.

The slideshow works and I got the HTML and CSS for the part which is supposed to sit on top of it ready as well. But I just can't figure out how to combine those two. I tried working with positive and negative z-index, but that doesn't work. Is there any way to actually set the Javascript slideshow as background, so that it won't affect my HTML and CSS?

Comment: try `position: absolute; z-index: 12;` on your words and let your slideshow have `z-index: 0;` If this doesn't work I think you need to show your code.

Comment: I tried it and it still does't work. Is there a way i can sed you the code?

Comment: Oh hi, why don't you just edit your question and include the code so everyone can help you? You can just post the relevant html and css.

Comment: editing the text won't work haha

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to add position:relative to the elements you're trying to use z-index on.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it figured out. position: absolute and z-index to 1000, while the Slider remains at z-index 0. :) thanks